# Meaning of $\uparrow$ in below d-separation algorithm from Koller

Tags: notation, bayesian-network, graphical-model, causal-diagram, d-separation

In *Probabilistic Graphical Models* by *Koller* and *Friedman* there is an algorithm to find the nodes reachable from node $X$ via trails that are active, given conditioning set $Z$. What is the meaning of "$\uparrow$" at line 22, in the algorithm given below (given in image format, due to its length)? -

[image]

Does "**trail up through $Y$**" denote configuration "**$\rightarrow Y \rightarrow$**"?

Comment: It is defined on line 12.

Comment: @whuber on line 12, does "$(X, \uparrow)$" mean - trails with "$\rightarrow X$" configuration?

Comment: The up-arrow is a symbol for "direction" as stated in the comment.

Comment: @whuber, I posted an answer below. Is it in sync with what you were suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

1. $\uparrow$ denotes travelling from children to their respective parents. $(M,\uparrow)$ denotes that $M$ is approached from its children - "... $\leftarrow M$".
2. $\downarrow$ denotes travelling from parents to their respective children. $(M,\downarrow)$ denotes that $M$ is approached from its parents - "... $\rightarrow M$".

We can see how this convention satisfies our notions of a trail being active.

**Case I** - $(M,\uparrow)$

The trail goes from a child node to $M$ and may extend from $M$

- either to its children, as in $\leftarrow M \rightarrow Y$, - "$(Y,\downarrow)$"
- or its parents, as in $\leftarrow M \leftarrow Y$. - "$(Y,\uparrow)$"

If $M$ is not observed, i.e., $M \notin Z$, both trails till $Y$ remain active. This is captured in lines 23-26.

**Case II** - $(M,\downarrow)$

The trail goes from a parent node to $M$ and may extend from $M$

- either to its children, as in $\rightarrow M \rightarrow Y$, - "$(Y,\downarrow)$"
- or its parents, as in $\rightarrow M \leftarrow Y$. - "$(Y,\uparrow)$"

If $M$ is not observed, $\rightarrow M \rightarrow Y$ remains active. If $M$ or its descendants are observed, i.e., $M \in A$, $\rightarrow M \leftarrow Y$ remains active. This is captured in lines 28-34.